# rabbitmq-diagnostics command not found

Tags: raspberry-pi, rabbitmq, raspbian

I just did a fresh install of RabbitMQ on my RaspberryPi with Raspbian Stretch 9.9, and I wanted to use the `rabbitmq-diagnostics` command to check status/ping and other monitoring info but it says the command cannot be found. I don't know if it comes bundled with RabbitMQ and if it does if I need to do something or if I need to install a plugin but there's virtually no documentation about that so I assume it just comes with RabbitMQ like `rabbitmqctl` does, but I have no idea why it isn't a command.

I've restarted my RaspberryPi several times, and the other commands work as they should. I've done a fair bit of searching online and I can't seem to find any info on it other than the official documentation page;

https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-diagnostics.8.html

Any help from anyone would really be great.

Answer (score 6):

Wasted 20 minutes on this.

I needed `rabbitmq-diagnostics` for getting environment and check for a key (`collect_statistics_interval`)

However, in my latest installation `rabbitmq-diagnostics` is missing.
Also, no help on installation on official website.

But found a workaround, see below:

`sudo rabbitmq-diagnostics environment | grep collect_statistics_interval`
is same as
`sudo rabbitmqctl eval 'application:get_env(rabbit, collect_statistics_interval).'`

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `rabbitmq` package doesn't have `rabbitmq-diagnostics`. You may fetch a higher version to install and thus get `rabbitmq-diagnostics`.

I checked `rabbitmq-server-3.5.6` in my env and I cannot find diagnostics either. However, I can find it in `rabbitmq-server-3.7.17`.